# Android: Message Search - open specific message conversation when tap on search results

Tags: android

I need some help for my project.

I made an android app that would search contacts, applications, and messaging within the device. The application and contacts are working, but I have a problem in messaging since it does not go to the conversation of the desired search message when you tap.

All I want is when you tap the search message it will go to the conversation. When I run my code it just goes to the conversation list instead of opening a specific conversation.
Here is the code in the message:

```
package com.android.searching.engines;

import java.util.List;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import com.android.searching.ContentManager.Results;

public class SmsEngine extends Engine {
    public SmsEngine(Context context, String type) {
        super(context, type);
        if (sSmsIcon == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            if (list != null && list.size() == 1) {
                sSmsIcon = list.get(0).loadIcon(pm);
            }
        }
    }
    private static Drawable sSmsIcon = null;
    private static String smsAll = "content://sms/";
    @Override
    protected void doSearch(Context context, Results results, String pattern, boolean isPresearch) {
        String selection = null;
        if (!pattern.equals("")) {
            selection = "address like '%" + pattern + "%' or body like '%" + pattern + "%'";
        }
        final Uri smsUri = Uri.parse(smsAll);
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(smsUri, null,
        selection, null, "date desc");
        if (cursor != null) {
            int idNum = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
            int addressNum = cursor.getColumnIndex("address");
            int bodyNum = cursor.getColumnIndex("body");
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                results.add(new SmsResult(null, cursor.getString(idNum), cursor.getString(addressNum), cursor.getString(bodyNum)));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    public class SmsResult extends Engine.IResult {
        protected SmsResult(Drawable icon, String id, String address, String body) {
            super(id, icon, address, body);
        }
        @Override
        public Drawable getIcon() {
            return sSmsIcon == null ? sDefaultIcon : sSmsIcon;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(Context context) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.mms",
            "com.android.mms.ui.Conversation"));
            intent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList");
            intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/"),
            Long.parseLong(mId));
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(uri);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Your response will be really helpful and appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You have more problems than that.  You're assuming the default SMS app is the users preferred app.  You can't even know for sure its installed (many OEMs replace it).  Your code will just flat out not work on many devices, and will do something that annoys the user on a lot of others.

Comment: ah.. how about this, i have a search interface and i want my results messages within the device, that when i tap it will go to the conversation, is it possible?

Comment: If anyone find solution for this. I've been facing same issue.